# AlertDialog.Builder is undefined

Tags: android

Thought I had it working but I get another error! I'm still new to Android and can't seem to fix this issue no matter what. I know it's to do with using "new Builder(this);". However I don't know what else to use, any help would be appreciated!

```
changeDay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);
            b.setTitle("Select Day");
            String[] types = {"1", "2", "3"};
            b.setItems(types, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int    which){
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    switch(which){
                    case 0:
                        day = "1";
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        day = "2";
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use  `AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);`  You aren't specifying the full name of the class, so it doesn't know what to use.

Comment: Thanks but this seems to just give the exact same error again!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the `String[]` array, the [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html) `setItems` method doesn't take `String[]` array as parameter, it takes `int` or `CharSequence[]`

Check here - [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems(int, android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setItems%28int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29)

**Update:** So the second part of the answer is, in your Builder(this) the `this` refers to the `OnClickListener`, you want it to refer to the `context` of the `Activity`. To do this you can simple put something like the following in your `onCreate()`

```
Context myCtx = this; //this sets the Activity as myCtx
```

then replace `Builder(this)` with `Builder(myCtx)`. Voila!

Comment: I've sorted that thank you! However I still have the same error appearing!
"The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"

Comment: Sure! I edited it into the previous comment but just to be sure you see it!
"The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"

Comment: so in this line `AlertDialog.Builder b = new Builder(this);` your `this` is referring to the View.OnClickListener(). You want it to point to the `context` of the `Activity`. I will update my answer with the solution.

Comment: Thanks so much! Finally! I'm starting to get a good understanding of Android thanks to fine people like yourself!

Comment: No worries Shaun! Good luck with your Android dev!

Comment: Also don't forget to upvote answers and accept correct answers to gain reputation here on stackoverflow.